# Best method to implement a filter/search in Django

Tags: jquery, django, filter

Building an application in django/jquery that deals with documents.
This `document` model has many attributes (name,price,author etc...)

So need to implement a filter/search functionality

**methods i know**:
**1.** Send ajax call to django, each time the user enters a character in search/filter input
**2.** Store your data on client side and render it using js/jquery and implement the filter using jquery

**Questions:**
**1.** is there some other methods to do the same ?
**2.** if no, which is the best of the above 2 methods ?

Do let me know if more clarity is required for the question.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I like [Haystack Search](http://haystacksearch.org/) to make searchs.
Currently has more than 700 forks on [github](https://github.com/django-haystack/django-haystack) and a has good [documentation](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/v2.4.0/toc.html).

> Search doesn't have to be hard. Haystack lets you write your search
>   code once and choose the search engine you want it to run on. With a
>   familiar API that should make any Djangonaut feel right at home and an
>   architecture that allows you to swap things in and out as you need to,
>   it's how search ought to be.

Comment: Needs a lot of customization.......... hence not planning to use any 3rd party packages